# PHP Manual: No version information available, might only be in Git

Tags: php, function, reference, manual

I see "No version information available, might only be in Git" when reading php manual. Could you please tell me what it means?

For example: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php

Comment: It means the docs site doesn't know what version of PHP the page is relevant to and that that information may exist only in the git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific extension is distributed via GitHub by Microsoft. That means they release different versions (or updates) for different version of php. Info about that is on their GitHub page: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql